# Isomorphism classes of gerbes over picard stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is well known that a picard stack on a site is equivalent to a two term complex of sheaves of abelian groups.

> Can we describe the isomorphism classes of gerbes of the picard stack using the two term complex?

Comment: If you consider the complex concentrated in degrees $-1$ and $0$, $\phi:E^{-1}\to E^0$, then probably the group of gerbes is the hypercohomology in degree $1$ of the global sections functor for the complex $E^\bullet$ (degree $1$ rather than $2$, because we already put the kernel of $\phi$ in degree $-1$).